# Image brightness with html5/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my project, I'm trying to create an ambient lighting feel. I handle images via client side coding and I need to adjust brightness of several images. I know there are libraries such as Pixastic, but I want a solution which applies directly into HTML code(like  tags) rather than Image objects in JS. Are there any Javascript or CSS based way to do it?

Comment: You could probably use the (IE-unsupported) `<canvas>` tag and load the images into there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Blender suggests, the `<canvas>` tag is what you want for gamma manipulation, which is a non-linear per-pixel transformation.

Answer (score 8):

You can try playing around with CSS opacity to see if that suits your needs.

```
img {
    opacity: 0.8; /* good browsers */
    filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* ye 'old IE */
}
```

Comment: though I doubt it would look good, one can put a white background behind the image, so as it becomes transparent, it just appears to get whiter and whiter ("brighter")

Comment: Using opacity was the first thing I thought. I tried to put a shadow layer on top of the image but it darkens the whole block. I just want to darken the image only.

Comment: Then put a black layer behind the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one with HTML5.

Checkout the one for brightness adjustment.

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

```
Filters.brightness = function(pixels, adjustment) {
  var d = pixels.data;
  for (var i=0; i<d.length; i+=4) {
    d[i] += adjustment;
    d[i+1] += adjustment;
    d[i+2] += adjustment;
  }
  return pixels;
};
```

Comment: it was a old post, please use this site to do and test html5 http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

Comment: dead link -1 :|

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if Pixastic can work on the results of `new Image` it can work on `<img>` elements in the document too.

Your options other than that are basically canvas imagedata manipulation (which won't work in IE8 or older) and SVG filters (which won't work in IE8 or older, and won't work on HTML elements directly in anything but Gecko).